# include в цикле while PHP

Tags: php, while, require

Есть PHP скрипт, который запрашивает из БД данные и обрабатывает результат в цикле:

```php
$sql1 = $db->query("SELECT * FROM swich");
while ($sw = $db->get_row($sql1)){
    require_once swich_DIR . $sw['phpclass'];
    $phpclass = array('ip' => $sw['ip'], 'realip' => $sw['realip'], 'ro' => $sw['ro'], 'rw' => $sw['rw']);
    $data_sw = new Swclass($phpclass); 
...
```

Код цикла большой, поэтому не вижу смысла выкладывать его весь. Собственно проблема возникает на 2й итерации когда `$sw['phpclass']` хранит/сообщает другую переменную, следовательно require надо сделать из другого файла, но цикл уже хранит *require* из 1й итерации.
Подскажите пожалуйста, куда копать?

Comment: А проблема как выражается? Ошибка на странице или что?

Comment: у вас там классы одинаково названы что ли в этих файлах?

Comment: Поставьте внутри цикла `while` простое сохранение в файл значения переменной `$sw['phpclass']` и увидите что у Вас в ней на каждой итерации сидит. Это же азы отладки...

Comment: при второй итерации require_once swich_DIR . $sw['phpclass']; уже "занята"(тоесть возвращает True)  и цикл/скрипт завершается.
@teran все верно, классы идентично названы, т.к. в других файлах вызов из бд происходит конкретной записи и проходить циклом по результату нет необходимости.

Comment: Какой-то бред, __что__ там занято и как? Почему ты решил что цикл завершается на второй итерации?

Comment: @u_mulder он в цикле подключает файлы, в каждом файле есть класс. вот наименования классов всегда одинаковы. поэтому на второй итерации ругается, что класс уже существует, и, наверное, на этом с фатальной ошибкой выпадает

Comment: при дебаге заканчивается как раз на шаге require_once swich_DIR . $sw['phpclass']. дебаг делаю через phpStorm. делаю пошагово 2ю итерацию и вот как раз после подключения файла все... выходит из скрипта @teran